# Cannot use instance member 'currColor' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

So I'm very new to Swift and hoping to self-teaching swift during this pandemic. 
I'm making an app and all it does is to change the color of a label when a button is pressed. 
My storyboard looks like this

```
    @IBAction func ChangeButton(_ sender: Any) {
        TopLeft.backgroundColor = CornerColor(c: TopLeft.backgroundColor!).getFirstColor()
    }
```

And my CornerColor class looks like this

```
    class CornerColor{

        var currColor : UIColor

        init(c : UIColor) {
            self.currColor = c
        }
        private static let colorsArray = [UIColor.black, UIColor.red, UIColor.yellow, UIColor.blue]

        var index = colorsArray.firstIndex(of: currColor)
        ....
    }
```

What I hope from index is that when the TopLeft.backgroundColor is passed to CornerColor class, it will read the color and see which position is the color in the array, then do index++ to get the next color.

However, it appears that in the "var index" line, it says "Cannot use instance member 'currColor' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available"

I don't really understand what's happening. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means you can't initialize a property which you have just created in the Class.
technically initializer is the first thing that gets executed in your Class, and if you use a property before an initializer is called, the property is not yet created.
What you can do is creating a method inside of your class and then call it after you initialized the class, something like this:

```
class CornerColor{

    var currColor : UIColor
    private static let colorsArray = [UIColor.black, UIColor.red, UIColor.yellow, UIColor.blue]
    var index : UIColor

    init(c : UIColor) {
        self.currColor = c
        self.getNextColor()
    }

    func getNextColor(){
        self.index = colorsArray.firstIndex(of: currColor)
    }
    ....
}
```

or you can call the method in your IBOutlet:

```
@IBAction func ChangeButton(_ sender: Any) {
    TopLeft.backgroundColor = CornerColor(c: TopLeft.backgroundColor!).getFirstColor()
    CornerColor.getNextColor()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Properties are initialised *before* `init()` is called (the order in code does not matter, just in case), that's why the error. Here is corrected variant

```
class CornerColor{

        var currColor : UIColor

        init(c : UIColor) {
            self.currColor = c
            self.index = colorsArray.firstIndex(of: c)
        }
        private static let colorsArray = [UIColor.black, UIColor.red, UIColor.yellow, UIColor.blue]

        var index: Int 
        ....
    }
```